# How can I read the state of a GPIO output in Rust?

Tags: rust, libgpiod, gpiod

I'm trying to implement a stateless process that doesn't have to track the state of the GPIO it's controlling: rather, I was hoping to read directly from the hardware if pins are set low or high.

For inputs, this doesn't appear to be a problem, but for outputs, it apparently is.

I'm using the `gpiod` crate for rust, which is based on `libgpiod`.  The same behaviour described in this issue: [Get value of a gpio output using libgpiod in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67300892/32836) is what I'm facing.

*Is there an "as-is" option, much like with more recent cli `gpioget` tools to accomplish this?*

This code is meant to toggle a given line on a given `Chip` ('chip'):

```
    let opts /* : Options<Output, [u32; 1], ... */ = Options::output([line]);
    let outputs : Lines<Output> = chip.request_lines(opts)?;
    let mut values: [bool; 1] = outputs.get_values([false])?;

    // Negate the values read from the 'outputs'
    values.iter_mut().for_each(|x| *x = !*x);

    // Switch the polarity of the lines on the outputs
    outputs.set_values(values)?;

    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_micros(hold_time_us));

    // Return the values read from the 'outputs' to their original state.
    values.iter_mut().for_each(|x| *x = !*x);

    // Return the outputs to their original state
    outputs.set_values(values)?;
```

but as soon as `outputs` goes out of scope, I don't know how to recover the state.

Comment: _I was hoping to read directly from the hardware if pins are set low or high._ You can't. It might work for one controller and not for another. It's **not** guaranteed by the Linux kernel to save the hardware state in between.

Comment: Even that answer doesn't tell that on some drivers it won't work anyway.

Comment: @0andriy Understood.  I looked at the kernel source for the GPIO module I happen to be using and that state _can_ be read directly from the hardware (and the driver makes that available to user space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like the [gpiod](https://crates.io/crates/gpiod) crate does not support `as-is`, only `input` or `output`.

You could use libgpiod's Rust bindings, i.e the [libgpiod](https://crates.io/crates/libgpiod) crate, or my [gpiocdev](https://crates.io/crates/gpiocdev) crate, both of those do support requesting a line `as-is`.

Requesting a line as an output always overrides the value, which you don't want, but you need to set the line as an output to set its value, so you would need to request it `as-is`, then reconfigure it as an `output` with the toggled value:

```rust
    let offset = 22;
    // request the line as-is
    let req = gpiocdev::Request::builder()
        .on_chip("/dev/gpiochip0")
        .with_line(offset)
        .request()?;

    // read the value
    let value = req.value(offset)?;
    println!("{offset}: {value} -> {}", value.not());

    // reconfigure the line as output with inverted value
    let mut config = req.config();
    req.reconfigure(config.as_output(value.not()))?;
```

Though, as @0andriy mentions, whether that works the way you want depends on the kernel GPIO driver for your hardware - the typical behaviour is to reset the line to its default state (often an input) when released.
It works for me on a Raspberry Pi (compiled as `toggle_line_value`):

```bash
$ toggle_line_value
22: inactive -> active
$ toggle_line_value
22: active -> inactive
$ toggle_line_value
22: inactive -> active
```

as the Raspberry Pi GPIO driver leaves the line in its current state when released.  YMMV.